# How can I get the file name for an input of file type in IE8

Tags: jquery, ajax, file, internet-explorer-8, upload

So background is I need to create a file upload control that submits files in a very specific fashion. Most users are on IE8 so I using a hidden iframe and a form post, but when the user selects the file using the file input my function kicks off.  I don't know how to retrieve just file name in IE8 since the file api is not supported.  In the example below the alert will output the full address, but this is not useful to me.  Any ideas?

```
<form>
     <input name="data" id="filesInput" onchange="handleFileSelect(this);" type="file" value=""/>
</form>

function loadFile(evt){
     alert(evt.value);
}
```

Comment: Can you not just traverse the address to retrieve just the part you want?

Comment: You can't do this. IE8 does'nt support any manipulation of the file data on the clientside, you'll need to do it serverside, or if there are any activeX solutions out there somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't evt.value contain the full filename, but having a fake path, something like

```
C:\fakepath\video.mp4
```

So, can you use:

```
var n = evt.target.value.substring(evt.target.value.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
```

Now n will contain just the filename.

Comment: n gives file name in all browsers but IE8 gives issue as "Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference".
How do I get value of input of type='file' in IE8?

Comment: Give up on IE8 ;p - or you'll have to fiddle with how the evt.target is reference - it maybe something else; use the browser dev tools to inspect evt and it's property chain.

Comment: This question asks about IE8. This solution does not work for IE8.